# SP2010 - After upload Doc ID is assigned, but using the Doc ID link results in No documents with the ID where found in this site collection

Tags: 2010, document-id

I have a farm with two WFEs and 9 site collections. I'm having a problem where users upload a document and then try to open the document using the Document ID Link, it returns "No documents with the ID *ID#* were found in this site collection".

Some times it takes 1-2 hours for the link to finally work. I get the feeling that this is controlled by a timer server or caching. If this is the case, where can I go to make this happen faster?

Using the link on the Document Name works fine, but i've been teaching people to use the Document ID link to ensure they don't get broken links if someone renames the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

The library had versioning turned on and the Draft Permissions were only allowing those with *edit* access to read draft documents.  Changing these permissions to allow those with Read access to view draft documents allowed the Search Service to crawl the draft documents.

**Research**

Because I wasn't getting any results when I crawled the library using Incremental and Full I started looking into the Search Service itself. I soon discovered that it was only picking up documents that were published atleast once, which made me suspect the versioning played a part.

The crawl account should technically be allowed to read all documents, however it is *by design* that the crawl account must be specifically allowed to view draft documents.

Comment: Where do I set the draft permissions? In the search service itself or in the doc lib?

Comment: On the document library

Answer (score 1):

The Document ID feature uses the Search to get the document for the requested ID. Thus, you will have to wait until the next crawl after you uploaded a new document before you can find it using its document ID. The only thing you could do is to reschedule the crawls.

Comment: I suspected that is what controls is, but i've got my crawls scheduled to do an incremental every 30 mins, full crawl is once a week. (I'm also using the FAST search server).

Comment: It doesn't pick up the document through an incremental or full crawl. I had a look at the crawl log and it's not crawling the new document, i'm not sure why. I should also mention that the documents are routed using Content Organizer rules.